# How to make PDF viewer in Node Js

Tags: mysql, node.js, backend, express-handlebars, pdf-viewer

I have created a website where pdfs can be uploaded and downloaded. I want to add the functionality that a user can preview the pdf before downloading it.
How can i do it ?

Comment: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Comment: i would also suggest using cloudinary, where you can upload, download, preview pdfs. also images, videos, etc all for free

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Mozilla's open source project [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/). It's under Apache license.

For the integration, you could also look at that tutorial: [How to Create a JavaScript PDF Viewer](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pdf-viewer-in-javascript--cms-32505)